# Problem with committting text files with non-ascii characters

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I have a html file that contain some Greek characters, and whenever I try to commit it I got:

commitlog: file="dummy.html" appears to be a BINARY
commitlog error: file="dummy.html" appears BINARY but checked in as ASCII
cvs commit: Pre-commit check failed

I am using: 
cvs add -kk dummy.html
cvs commit dummy.html

Is there any way to workaround this and commit file as text and not as binary.

Thanks

Comment: adding more info: 
my environment:  Windows XP SP3, CVS v1.11.22  in combination with TortoiseCVS v1.10.10

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your files are encoded. If you use utf-8 for example, CVS could treat this as normal text files.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this file with the following command:

**cvs add -kb**

if you want binary file, try:

cvs add -ko